# What is the ruby equivalent of the PHP MongoID class?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'd like to be able to search documents by ID but I can't for the life of me figure out how to encode a MongoID the same way that one does in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php

```
$id = new MongoID($id_str); //This is how it would be in PHP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  this

```
BSON::ObjectId(id_str)
```

Comment: FYI ... all you need to do is this: BSON::ObjectId(id_str) ... from_string will fail

Comment: Well, in my case `new` was failing, and `from_string` is working. Strange, huh?

Comment: @NickONeill: my bad, I was calling `new`. But `from_string` is working also (on my machine)